# Get values from database according to attribute send in the http in Mule

Tags: mysql, mule

I have very simple application using mule. this application should retrieve some value from DB defined by value (name of person) send by http request.
I used the example used here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/database-connector-examples

My flow:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration_DB2"
        host="localhost" port="8092" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
    <flow name="database_connector_mysql2Flow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration_DB2"
            path="/*" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select Id, name, lastname, Email, phone from employee where name=#[message.inboundProperties['name']];]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>
```

After running the application, I set the following url in the browser:

```
http://localhost:8092/?name=Karam
```

But all what I get is only empty bracket [ ]

I am suspecting this part of mySql query is not correct:

> where name=#[message.inboundProperties['name']]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the script at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/database-connector-examples

Do you have name column in your employee table? And do you have any records for name 'Karam'?

change the query to 
`where name=#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.name]`

Comment: I use another database. I have recod name for 'Karam'

Comment: Also if I use the following query: select Id, name, lastname, Email, phone from employee where name='Karam'; it works without problem. only problem comes when I use where name=#[message.inboundProperties['name']];

Comment: That is what it is said in the answer... you are passing query parameter in `http://localhost:8092/?name=Karam` and in sql query you are using `inboundProperties` which will not work... use `#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.name]` instead

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary thank you. that solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic-query instead of parameterized query.